# Excel is made unreadable after writing new excel file

Tags: excel, go

I am trying to take data from one excel file (a) to another (b). The two files are different templates, when I copy the data from (b) to (a), I then save (a) to a new file name (c) so that I can use (a) as a template again.

After I save the file, as I would expect (c) to now appear as (a) with data from (b), instead (c) is unreadable and I see the message

```
"Excel found unreadable contents in "...."
```

Further message is provided upon opening the file

```
"Removed Records: Style from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)"
```

Can someone see what I am missing or doing incorrectly to cause this issue?

Thank you

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    //Read data from v2 template
        var inputSlice [][][]string
    inputSlice, errRead := xlsx.FileToSlice("v2_template.xlsx")
        if errRead != nil{
        fmt.Println("failed to read file")
    }

    //open v1 template file for writing
    var outputFileTemplate, errOpen = xlsx.OpenFile("v1_template.xlsx")
    if errOpen != nil{
        fmt.Println("failed to open file")
    }

    accountSheet := outputFileTemplate.Sheet["Account"]
    indx := 2
    for a,sheet := range inputSlice[0][4:][:] {
        if a < len(inputSlice)+1 { //check if first field has value
            accountSheet.AddRowAtIndex(indx)
            accountSheet.Rows[indx].AddCell()
            accountSheet.Rows[indx].Cells[0].SetString(sheet[:][0])
        }
     }

     //save output file
     t := time.Now()
     outfile := "final_v1.xlsx"
     outputFilename := t.Format("./20060102150405") + "_" + outfile
     //see if it is readable
     outputFileTemplate.Save(outputFilename)
}
```

Here are the sheets I am using for this code here:

(a) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rh16Zanknbke-segnn_GZx7j8mGczmKL/view?usp=sharing
(b) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRWRzsofvmzsP2LdYae3p7baVtekE0Wr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't ignore errors (e.g. like the one returned by the `Save` method). And when checking errors, don't continue on after printing a generic message that doesn't include the error (in `main` it's probably sufficient to use `log.Fatalln("some message:", err)` in place of your `fmt.Println` calls).

Comment: I will add that in, thanks for pointing it out!